# Formatear fecha en Javascript menor a 1970

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

Tengo una fecha menor a 1970, en este caso **06/10/1943**, y la mando desde ASP.NET a Javascript por AJAX, y esta llega con el formato **/Date(-828046800000)/**. En JS tengo una funcion para transformar estos formatos a texto, es esta:

```
function fixFecha(fecha) {
    debugger;
    if (fecha == null) {
        return '';
    }
    else {
        var codigo_fecha = parseInt(fecha.replace("/Date(", "").replace(")/", ""));
        var fecha1 = new Date(codigo_fecha).toLocaleDateString("es-AR");
        var fecha_formato = $.format.date(fecha1, "dd-MM-yyyy");

        return fecha_formato;
    }
}
```

Estoy seguro que funciona bien, pero hoy probe con una fecha menor a 1970, y me lo convierte a **05/10/1943**, es decir, me esta restando un dia, alguien sabe por que puede pasar esto? Me imagino que sera por algo de que es menor a 1970 pero no estoy seguro.
Gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intenté usar `$.format.date()`, pero no encontré referencia, supongo que puede ser un plugin de *jQuery* u otra librería, pero se puede hacer directamente con objetos de fecha.

Seguramente la diferencia se debe a la zona horaria. Creando una variable global almacenas los milisegundos a agregar/descontar y luego lo aplicas en la función.

```js
// Diferencia horaria en minutos * 60 (segundos) * 1000 (milisegundos)
let diferencia = new Date().getTimezoneOffset() * 60000;

function fixFecha(fecha) {
    if (fecha == null) {
        return '';
    } else {
        // Obtener milisegundos pasados por parámetro
        // y aplicar diferencia horaria
        let miliSec = parseInt(fecha.replace('/Date(', '').replace(')/', '')) + diferencia;
        // Crear fecha y establecer formato
        let fecha1 = new Date(miliSec).toLocaleDateString("es-AR", {year: 'numeric', month: '2-digit', day: '2-digit'});
        return fecha1;
    }
}

console.log(fixFecha('/Date(-828046800000)/')); // 06/10/1943
console.log(fixFecha('/Date(0)/'));             // 31/12/1969
console.log(fixFecha('/Date(84600000)/'));      // 01/01/1970
```